# fixed size box with math

Tags: math-mode, size, box

Is there a way to code :

```
\begin{aligned}
& \boxed{\cos(30)}~x + \boxed{-\cos(20)}~y = \boxed{0} \\
& \boxed{-\sin(30)}~x + \boxed{\sin(20)}~y = \boxed{100} \\
\end{aligned}
```

And have boxes with fixed size like this :

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the question is whether one can make all the boxes equally wide, the answer is yes. With `eqparbox`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\newcommand{\Boxed}[2][A]{\fbox{\eqmakebox[#1][c]{$\mathstrut#2$}}}
\begin{document}
\[\begin{aligned}
 \Boxed{\cos(30)}~x + \Boxed{-\cos(20)}~y &= \Boxed{0} \\
 \Boxed{-\sin(30)}~x + \Boxed{\sin(20)}~y &= \Boxed{100} \\
\end{aligned}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]